# How do I forward incoming calls from USA to Philippines number in Twilio?

Tags: twilio

How do I forward incoming calls from USA to Philippines number in Twilio? I have created a studio flow, but it does not connect the call

Comment: Can you share the Studio flow that you created? Have you published the flow? Have you connected the flow to your Twilio number?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.